# Is it possible to make a wordpress plugin run only on publish, not on update?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written a wordpress plugin that requires our writers to pick a topic from an external site.  It will not allow the writer to publish the article unless a topic from the external site is associated with it.  When the article is published, the topic they chose is updated on the external site and, therefore, on an option to select again.
This all works as expected.  My problem is that when a user updates an article that has already been published, and therefore, the topic is no longer an option to choose, the plugin stops them from updating because there is no topic.
My question is: Is there a way to ensure the plugin only runs when a post is initially published, not when it is updated?

Here is the code (with parts removed):

```
<?php
*/
Plugin Name: name
Description: Make sure writers articles are associated with a name topic.
*/
add_action('add_meta_boxes','name_add_meta_boxes');

add_action('save_post', 'complete_name_topic');


function name_add_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box(
            'name',
            'name',
            'name_html',
            'post',
            'normal'
    );
}


function name_html($post){
    wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'name_nonce');
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $f_name = utf8_encode($current_user->user_firstname);
    $l_name = utf8_encode($current_user->user_lastname);
    if(!$f_name || !$l_name){
            $display_name = str_replace(' ', '%20', $current_user->display_name);
    }else{
            $display_name = $f_name.'%20'.$l_name;
    }
    $bar = json_decode(www.example.com));
    $foo = get_object_vars($bar);
    echo '<select name="name"><option value="">Choose name Topic</option>';
    foreach($foo as $id => $topic){
    echo "<option value='$id'>$topic</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';
}

function complete_name_topic($post_id) {
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
            return;
    if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['name_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__)))
            return;
    $id = wp_is_post_revision($post_id);
    if(!$id){
            $permalink = get_permalink($post_id);
    }else{
            $permalink = get_permalink($id);
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name'])){
            $message = 72;
            global $wpdb;
            $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array('post_status' => 'pending'), array('ID' => $post_id));
            add_filter('redirect_post_location', create_function('$location', 'return add_query_arg("message", "'.$message.'", $location);'));
    }else{
            $ch = curl_init('www.example.com');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "URL=$permalink");
            curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
    }
}


add_filter('post_updated_messages', 'name_error_message');
function name_error_message($messages){
    $messages['post']['**'] = 'A name topic must be associated with this post.';
    return $messages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you `update_post_meta` the first time through, you can `get_post_meta` to discover whether that has happened already on subsequent updates.

Comment: That's a good solution.  My only problem is that I would also need it to ignore the posts that already exist.  They wouldn't have the meta_data set as they were completed before I added that line of code.  So they would proceed as before, causing an issue.

Comment: I see what you mean. Updating the metadata of all existing posts at plugin install is a possibility, though not an appealing one. What about comparing the post's post_date with the installation time of the plugin?

Comment: That would work, but I'm rather new to wordpress (this is my first plugin) and I'm not sure how to access the installation time of the plugin.  I know I can hook to the activation and set something but I'm not sure where to set it so the scope is outside the existence of the plugin.  I tried using `publish_post` and then checking `if(get_post_status('$id') == publish)` before proceeding (if it did it was an update) but it was always found to be true.  I guess it's updating the status before running the plugin.  Now I'm looking at hooking to `wp_transition_post_status`.

Comment: oh yeah, I wasn't aware of wp_transition_post_status -- that looks like it might be promising